# Using deepgram_captions for OpenAI's Whisper

Tags: python, json, openai-whisper

Trying to turn a Whisper response into a timestamped subtitle file where each line in the subtitle has been set to around 10 (you can't natively do that in OpenAI's Whisper yet)

I have the following code I've based on the limited deepgram_captions documentation:

```
with open(path.join(audio_directory, 'final_script.flac'), "rb") as f:
    whisper_response = client.audio.transcriptions.create(model="whisper-1", file=f, response_format='verbose_json')
    transcription = WhisperTimestampedConverter(whisper_response)
    captions = srt(transcription, 10) #error happening at this line
```

However, I've been getting the error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'Transcription' object has no attribute 'get'
```

at the commented line.

I've tried the following but keep getting errors:

- Using DeepgramConverter instead of WhisperTimestampedConverter
- Making the response_format: 'srt', 'json' and 'verbose_json'

How can I get the correct response from Whisper to feed into Deepgram? The documentation says a JSON is fine. (https://github.com/deepgram/deepgram-python-captions/tree/main)

Here's the response I get when I do 'json':

```
Transcription(text="Example text example text.... ")
```

and for 'verbose_json':

```
Transcription(text="Example text, example text.", task='transcribe', language='english', duration=407.1099853515625, segments=[
{'id': 0, 'seek': 0, 'start': 0.0, 'end': 3.799999952316284, 'text': ' Example text Example text Example text', 'tokens': [*token_list*], 'temperature': 0.0, 'avg_logprob': -0.2326301634311676, 'compression_ratio': 1.6376811265945435, 'no_speech_prob': 0.05089477077126503},
{'id': 1, 'seek': 0, 'start': 3.799999952316284, 'end': 7.440000057220459, 'text': ' More example text more example text,', 'tokens': [*token_list*], 'temperature': 0.0, 'avg_logprob': -0.2326301634311676, 'compression_ratio': 1.6376811265945435, 'no_speech_prob': 0.05089477077126503},
{'id': 2, 'seek': 0, 'start': 7.440000057220459, 'end': 11.359999656677246, 'text': ' and find the strength and peace we need to face each day.', 'tokens': [*token_list*], 'temperature': 0.0, 'avg_logprob': -0.2326301634311676, 'compression_ratio': 1.6376811265945435, 'no_speech_prob': 0.05089477077126503}, etc.)
```

NOTE: I can see there's no "get" in my response, but I do not know how to get the correct response.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you have an update? I have the same question